# What is my running version of cups?

Tags: rhel, cups, version

I am running RedHat 7.1 and have installed, using yum, Cups 1.6.3.
Then I manually compiled in a version of Cups 2.0
This did not resolve my PDF printing issue as I had hoped it would.
So I want to double-check that version 2 is now in place.

How to determine the version of Cups that I am now running?

`sudo yum list | grep cups`  still shows it as 1.6.3 (but that is understandable).
One problem - I have not configured the GUI web-based interface, so that is not an answer for me.

Comment: If I use the command `curl http://localhost:631` I get an HTML file back from Cups which shows the version number between the <TITLE> tags.

This looks like a valid answer to me question.  Albeit only testing the installation and not checking the executable file's version.

Comment: `cups-config --api-version`